# Particular array sorting

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I've a strange question: Which is the smart/best way to order an array of number like this

```
[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]
```

to this

```
[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

The idea is to balance the list in order to give a sort of priority to each element of the list. 
Language could be php, it does not matter that much

Comment: Please add the language you are using as a tag, so that it will be easy to answer.

Comment: Could you describe the exact rules of your sorting?

Comment: How do you feel list 2 is balanced than 1? explain that balancing factor properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say we have [1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3]
Take first set of equal numbers and put it in seperate arrays ( vertically )

```
1 1
```

similarly for second set of equal numbers and so on

```
1 1 
2 2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Concat the arrays to get the result

```
[1,2,3][1,2,3][2,3][2]
```

Comment: That's interesting, and to concat the arrays vertically? The only way I can think is to iterate, or creating a matrix with length the maximum size of an array and height the number of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each element in your array and copy it into a second array, where each element also includes a second sort key that is the sequence number.

So lets call your input array A.

First: Sort A

Then: iterate over A and copy each element into a new array B, where each element has a second sort key, call them key1 and key2. Key1 is the value from A, key2 is the sequence number.

```
A: 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4
B: (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2),(4,1),(4,2)
```

Now create a comparison function for elements of B that orders first on key2 and then on key1:

```
bool isSmallerThan( x, y )
{
   if ( x.key2 < y.key2 ) return true;
   if ( x.key2 > y.key2 ) return false;
   if ( x.key1 < y.key1 ) return true;
   return false;
}
```

Now sort B using the new comparison function.

Iterate over B and copy all the key1s back into A.